# Troubleshooting usb connected drives in VirtualBox with Win7 and Win8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, usb, virtualbox

I installed vbox 4.2 (went back from 4.3 after it became unstable) with a win7 sp1 guest and win8.1 host. USB 2 connectivity does not work. It complains that "USB device is busy with a previous request" when I attempt to connect in virtualbox. I tried with filters and without filters, usb 2 support enabled and disabled, etc. Nothing works.

The logical assumption is that the host is doing something with the drive. But, how in the world do I find out what it is and make it stop?

Many thanks in advance

Joe

Answer (score 0):

It is an old bug, you find it reported [in this VirtualBox ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4656). They state that the solution is to disable USB 2.0 EHCI support in the host BIOS. You can try that.

Comment: I would love to, except my bios has no such option :(. I will recheck.